# Comparing AD users with File Names

Tags: file, loops, powershell, exception

I'm trying to find files that are named after members of a specific AD group with a `foreach` loop using the code below. The script seems to have a problem which causes the loop to stop after the first exception. I think I need to throw the exception because there seems to be no default return value or error if no file for one of the group members is found.

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
$BVAU = Get-ADGroupMember ADGroupName | Select-Object -Property Name
foreach($entry in $BVAU) {
    trap [System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException]{
        Write-Host $_.Exception.Message
        continue
    }
}
if (-not (Get-ChildItem "\\samplepath" -Recurse | Where-Object FullName -like "*$entry*")) {
    throw [System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException] "$entry not found" 
}
}
```

I only want to display the group members that don't have an equally named file. (A PDF form that legally qualifies the AD group membership)

Comment: so you have a folder say c:\temp and there are several `*.pdf` files and you want to check, whether there is a pdf file with the same name as the group? Also, do you need to recursivly scan for that files?

Comment: Your bracing seems a bit off, I see 3 start braces but 4 end braces...?

Comment: The AD Group enables its members to connect to our company network from home. Those Users also have to sign an Agreement for this. The signed forms are stored as .pdf files in a specific folder. This specific folder has subfolders for each version of the agreement, which means I have use recursion. I want to find out which Group members  didn't sign that Agreement (no .pdf file is found where the file name contains the AD full name of a Group member).

Answer (score 0):

The `if` statement belongs inside the loop, and the `trap` should be defined before the loop. However, you don't need the `trap` in the first place, because it's pointless to throw exceptions just for echoing a username. Simply echo the name right away and continue. Also, avoid running code multiple times if it doesn't need to.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem "\\samplepath" -Recurse |
         Select-Object -Expand Basename -Unique
Get-ADGroupMember ADGroupName |
    Select-Object -Expand Name |
    Where-Object { $files -notcontains $_ } |
    ForEach-Object { "$_ not found" }
```

The above is assuming that the usernames aren't just partial matches of the file basenames. Otherwise the `Where-Object` filter becomes slightly more complicated:

```
...
Where-Object { $n = $_; -not ($files | Where-Object {$_ -like '*$n*'}) } |
...
```

Comment: Since the file names only match partially I used the second filter, but it didn't show any results or errors.

Comment: Sorry, I got the logic "upside down" in the second example. Please try again.